# ImportError: cannot import name UserSerializer while creating a demo rest api

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

I am trying to build a rest service on Django Rest Framework as per the [this](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/) tutorial.

I followed all the steps when I am trying to run

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

The following error is raised:

```
File "/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
File "/tutorial/tutorial/urls.py", line 24, in <module>
from tutorial.quickstart import views
File "/tutorial/tutorial/quickstart/views.py", line 6, in <module>
from tutorial.quickstart.serializers import UserSerializer,    GroupSerializer
ImportError: cannot import name UserSerializer
```

Comment: Check if you have that serializer in place. Do you have also `tutorial.quickstart.serializers` module?

Comment: Check have created this file `tutorial/quickstart/serializers.py` and in this file do you have class `class UserSerializer` which you have used in your views?

Comment: I do have that file created

Answer (score 3):

make sure the info is actually in the serializers.py and **tutorial** is project name and **quickstart** your app name

Then you can just write

```
from .serializers import UserSerializer, GroupSerializer
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the word "tutorial" from it. Use:

```py
from quickstart.serializers import UserSerializer, GroupSerializer
```

Comment: Hmm how is this going to help when the other imports worked